# If an inequality has solutions or not

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms

I am trying an problem in analysis but the solution depends upon whether the following inequality is solvable or not

> $n \geq (\log n)^{3n} $ .

I have no idea on how to find solutions (if any) 
of this inequality.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you want $n$ to come from (the natural numbers?)? What do you mean by $\log^{3n}$? Is it power to the $3n$ or the $3n$th iteration?

Comment: Doesn't $n=1$ work?

Comment: @Severin Schraven n belong to natural numbers. It is log (n) raised to power 3n .

Comment: Then saulspatz gave you a solution :)

Comment: Using a graphing calculator or anything, you see that $n=\approx 11.808$ is the intersection between $y=n$ and $y=(\log(n)^{3n})$, so all solutions between 1 and 11.808 works.

Comment: @GarethMa: on this site, $\log$ usually denotes the natural logarithm.

Comment: Sorry for that, I used desmos which naturally was base 10.My mistake thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(\log n)^{3n}$$ is a fast growing function and the shortest way to solve the inequation is probably to try the integers systematically.

$$0,0.11\cdots,2.33\cdots,50.38\cdots$$ leaves little doubt.

---

If the question is understood as $$n>\log_{10}n$$ the sequence is, starting from $10$,

$$1,3.37\cdots,15.53\cdots$$